# Testing Phone Number using Selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, automation

I have given a task by my Project Manager and he has asked me to "Test a phone number using selenium". He has asked me to cover all the test cases possible to test a phone number

The test cases are given below:
1. Phone number must contain digits only.
2. Phone number length should be 10.
3. It should not contain alphabets.
4. It should not contain symbols.
5. It should not contain the combination of alphanumerics.
6. Phone number should not start with 0.

Please help me in testing all these test cases in automation.

Comment: Your profile says you are a Senior test engineer.

Comment: How about you google 'selenium' and write up the code... If you get stuck add the relevant code here for someone to look at.

Answer (score 0):

i conform with the comments above, in agreement; i also don't condone answering questions like this, but something like this is so easy in selenium that it won't take me long to write.

this is all pseudo-code in java.

```
void testCase1() {
  // digits only
  setPhoneNumber("+12345a5434")
  clickSubmit()
  validateErrorMessage("ERROR: Your phone number contains letters")
}

void testCase2() {
  // length should be ten
  setPhoneNumber("+123456789")
  clickSubmit()
  validateErrorMessage("ERROR: Phone numbers should be ten-digits long")
}

void testCase3() {
  testCase1()  // this test case is the exact same as #1
}

void testCase4() {
  setPhoneNumber("+|123456t890")
  clickSubmit()
  validateErrorMessage("ERROR: Your phone number contains invalid characters")
}

void testCase5() {
  testCase1()
  testCase3()
  testCase4()
  // already covered in both these cases
}

void testCase6() {
  setPhoneNumber("+0123456789")
  clickSubmit()
  validateErrorMessage("ERROR: your phone number starts with 0")
}

void validTestCase() {
  setPhoneNumber("+1234567890")
  clickSubmit()
  validateErrorMessage(null)
  validateElementPresent(".success")
}
```

mind you this is al pseudo-code.  you don't specify which language you are using, nor any html.  I don't condone answering this type of question - but your task is so easy that i figured i'd write it out in pseudo-code.